# Only one method to implement onTouchListener() to multiple buttons

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use just one onTouchListener() for multiple buttons and this is the code i have,but its not working. 
What i want to do is when i press the button up,if there is another button pressed(right or left) to write a code and if its not pressed another button to write another code. I'm pretty new to java so there might be a lot of mistakes.
If you have another solution for my problem please help!

```
 abstract class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{

       public boolean OnTouch(View v,MotionEvent event){
           switch (v.getId()){
               case R.id.btnup:
                   switch (v.getId()){
                       case R.id.btnright:
                           mBluetooth.write("#1001#");
                           break;
                       case R.id.btnleft:
                           mBluetooth.write("#1002#");
                           break;
                       case R.id.btnup:
                           mBluetooth.write("#1000#");
                           break;
                   }
                   break;
               case R.id.btnright:
                   mBluetooth.write("#0002#");
                   break;
               case R.id.btnleft:
                   mBluetooth.write("#0001#");
                   break;
               case R.id.btndown:
                   switch (v.getId()){
                       case R.id.btnright:
                           mBluetooth.write("#2001#");
                           break;
                       case R.id.btnleft:
                           mBluetooth.write("#2002#");
                           break;
                       case R.id.btndown:
                           mBluetooth.write("#2000#");
                           break;
                   }


           }
      return true; }
   }}
```

This are the buttons:

```
    btnup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnup);
    btndown=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btndown);
    btnleft=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnleft);
    btnright=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnright);



     MyTouchListener touchListener = new MyTouchListener();
    btnup.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Comment: It seems you are only setting up the `touchListener` to the `btnup`, maybe you need to set it up for the others as well?

Answer (score 0):

What I've noticed:

- drop the `abstract` keyword in your listener class (you can't create instances of abstract classes).
- your outer switch seems fine, but inner ones (the ones detecting additional button being pressed) don't make sense.
- make sure you set the listener to all four buttons.

The `v` view you are receiving in your listener, is the view that got pressed (or released, or cancelled). In order to detect if button X is being pressed simultaneously while button Y is, you need to use information from the `MotionEvent` object that tells you if the event was a press or a release, and keep the state for each button. You can see a simple example of handling motion events [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158502/7156483). Also check Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) on MotionEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `void setTag (Object tag)` ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object))) to set Bluetooth command code for each button like this:

```
btnup.setTag("#1000#");
btndown.setTag("#2000#");
btnleft.setTag("#1002#");
btnright.setTag("#1001#");
```

and than in `OnTouch` something like that:

```
public boolean OnTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
  mBluetooth.write((String)v.getTag())
}
```

P.S. Seems You have wrong nested `switch` statements. You need analyze `v.getId()` and  `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` or something like that, not `v.getId()` every time.